# Laragon error 404 proyect can't upload images

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, laragon

I duplicated a Laravel project and set it up on Laragon, I've used phpmyadmin for the database and everything works out, except it can't upload the images that are on the folder uploads.

It gives me an error 404 with the following message:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/Qdm7qc4CXB.png 404 (Not Found)

What should I do?

Comment: did you make php artisan storage:link?

Comment: I hadn't. I tried it but the error persists :/